# What should I do when a job was posted on two different sites with slighly different requirements?

Tags: job-search, applications, job-description

A few days ago I found a job posting on Indeed, and I applied for it **through** that site. **No email from the company was provided in the posting**, you provide your details (name, email/phone), upload your resume/cover letter and click apply, and the site handles the rest of it. The deadline was **Jan 16th**, as stated in the posting.

Earlier today I decided to take the time to get to know the company a little better, and I happened to click on the careers section on the **company** website. I found the same job posting with a few details changed, instead of the deadline being Jan 16, it's **Jan 25**, the company posting also provides an email address to send your resume and cover letter. None of this was written into the post on Indeed.

I don't want to miss this opportunity, do I apply again, or just wait? **I followed all the instructions on the Indeed posting**. I didn't think to check the official site, perhaps if anything I'll remember this as a lesson to always check the company website for extra details.

Comment: Could it be a fairly similar position but in two different teams (and different managers) of the same employer?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen - It's the same posting. I compared both, and it's word for word the same.

Comment: That doesn’t mean that they can’t be be different positions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation to people, in these types of scenarios, is to err on the side of over-communicating. In today's competitive world, it's best to get your name in front of as many people as possible. You regularly have to work to keep your name at the top of lists as well, as your name can easily get lost in a sea of resumes and applications.

Without knowing exactly what happened at the company internally, there are a few scenarios that come to mind:

- They had someone accept the job, but later fell through. Hence, they had to re-post the job.
- This is for an additional headcount, for the same job role.
- There are simple inconsistencies between job posting websites and the company's official job site.

If you don't want to miss the opportunity, apply as many times as is necessary to demonstrate your interest to the employer. The worst they can do is turn you down once or more. Just send them an e-mail to express your interest, and let them know that you had originally applied on Indeed.com. However, let them know that you are excited about this position, and wanted to "double-check" that your name was in the running. You can even include a cover letter in the e-mail which further demonstrates your genuine interest, since they asked for it.

Either way, the bottom line is that a lack of action will guarantee you don't get a job. Sending (polite) reminder communications is rarely seen as aggressive, and is often appreciated, depending on who's reading it.